# Get all facebook album ids using FQL android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-fql

> Hi, 
>   I am trying to get all album ids from android user this way:

```
    Bundle params2 = new Bundle();
    params2.putString("method", "fql.query");
    params2.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
    params2.putString("query", "SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner=me()"); 
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner2 = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncRunner2.request(null, params,new AlbumNamesListener(),null);
```

in the AlbumNamesListener I am trying to see the response and it shows me: 
{"error_code":3,"error_msg":"Unknown method","request_args":[{"key":"access_token","value":"fffffffff9ZD"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}.

What am I doing wrong? please give me a tip how to get all album ids from user in android app.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct FQL query: `SELECT aid from album WHERE owner = me()`

Use that one instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I tried your FQL and still I got the same error. Do you have idea what can cause this error? do you have better idea to get all the album ids from the user ?

Comment: Remove `params2.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());`, you do not need to include your access token in the params because our SDK already appends that for you

Comment: Do you know if this : myresponse = facebook.request("me/albums"); should return me all the album ids ?

Comment: Yup, take a look at this request: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums%3Ffields%3Did